# Visual Studio Code PHP debugger doesn't stop on breakpoints while remote debugging

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, homestead

I'm using vscode php debugger extension with homestead laravel.
The problem is when i try to debug remotely this debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoints i spent quite long time to resolve this error but unfortunately couldn't find any solution that can solve my problem..

Here is my enviroment

phpinfo() :

[image: phpinfo()] 
[image: phpinfo()]
[image: phpinfo()]

Homestead.yaml :

[image: homestead]

php.ini from homestead :

[image: php.ini]

launch.json :

[image: launch.json]

Basically i followed [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/josecanhelp/7459ea73b07475906853aa94e5d36a75) and some others also i tried xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 which i found from this community but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated  thank you for reading.

**--------------------------Edited-------------------------**

One more thing about my situation when i set the breakpoints as everything it stops on nowhere which i can't see where it is with this error.
Every stepping throws that kind of error

[image: file not found]

**--------------------------Edited 2-------------------------**

I figured why those such files are not found. The pathMappings in the launch.json it was 'code' not 'Code' since i changed it that file not found error was gone but still it's pretty weird it stops on the breakpoints only when exception occurs so still i can't debug

Comment: what about xdebug.remote_host is that the local IP address of your machine

Comment: @S0HS I tried just now but it didn't work

Comment: which extension do you use?

Comment: [PHP Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) this one

Comment: Any solutions @Ihave10fingers? Did you solve it?